# AWS beanstalk worker instance deployment error: no Module, no attribute

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a worker app on AWS beanstalk. It is just a python file, and a .yml file for configuration. However, I failed to deploy the app. I am getting the following error in the log:

```
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: worker.init_process()
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: super().init_process()
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: self.load_wsgi()
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: self.callable = self.load()
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: return self.load_wsgiapp()
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Jul  1 22:40:13 ip-172-31-27-101 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
```

I am also getting the following errorL

```
Jul  2 19:28:34 ip-172-31-28-100 web: Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'application'.
```

Anyone knows what the application module is referring to here?
I certainly don't have any python package set up, since it is not necessary... I just run `python app.py` locally and it works. Would appreciate it if anyone can share some insights! thanks

Folder structure

```
.
├── README.md
├── application.py
├── cron.yaml
├── init
├── requirements.txt
└── worker.zip
```

application.py

```
application = flask.Flask(__name__)


@application.route('/')
def main():
   print("endpoint")
   return("ok"), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host="localhost")
```

wgsi.py

```
from application import application
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just run python app.py locally and it works.

By default the python applications on ElasticBeanstalk would be called:

```
application.py
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help! however, I have already changed it to application.py but it is still failing the same err: no module named application ....

Comment: @Erin Can you update your question with the structure of your zip and applicaion folder? Also make sure that the `application.py` is in the root of your zip, not any subfolder.

Comment: added. Could you take a look? Thanks! The zip is just all files compressed

Comment: @Erin  Thanks.  This `from application import application ` does not seem right. What do you want to achieve? And why are you modifying `wgsi.py`?